# Self Join to calcuate one day before a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this table *Employee_Hire* which has Hire date of an employee (ID) in a Department. Now I want to write a Select query which adds one more column (Last_day) to show last day he worked in that department. For instance, for ID = 1 in department D01 his last day was 2014/12/31. Similarly in D02 his last day was 2017/12/31.

Now since he is still working in D04, we can have a string like 'Till Present' or a future date like 2099/12/31 or anything which serves the purpose.

I want to do this for each employee in the table.

```
+---+-------------+------------+
| Id| Dept_name   | Hiredate   |
+---+-------------+------------+
| 1 |      D01    | 2012-01-01 |
| 1 |      D02    | 2015-01-01 |
| 1 |      D03    | 2018-01-01 |
| 1 |      D04    | 2019-01-01 |
| 2 |      D01    | 2010-01-01 |
| 2 |      D02    | 2012-01-01 |
| 3 |      D01    | 2008-01-01 |
| 3 |      D02    | 2010-01-01 |
| 3 |      D03    | 2012-01-01 |
| 4 |      D01    | 2015-01-01 |
| 4 |      D02    | 2017-01-01 |
+---+-------------+------------+
```

I know this can be done using LEAD OR LAG function but can anyone please tell me how to do this using Self Join?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ROW_NUMBER() function isn't also off limits, this query uses an actual self join:

```
SELECT
    curr.Id,
    curr.Dept_name,
    curr.Hiredate,
    DATEADD(day, -1, next.Hiredate) AS Last_day
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY HireDate) AS RowNum
    FROM EmployeeHire
) AS curr
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY HireDate) AS RowNum
    FROM EmployeeHire
) AS next
    ON curr.ID = next.ID AND curr.RowNum = next.RowNum - 1
```

I'm not sure how you could do a self join when sorting by arbitrary criteria without the ROW_NUMBER() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()` and date arithmetics:

```
select
    t.*,
    dateadd(
        day, 
        -1, 
        lead(hiredate, 1, '2100-01-01') over(partition by id order by hiredate)
    ) last_day
from mytable t
```

The second argument to `lead()` is the offset (here, you want the "next" row, so `1`), and the third is the default value, that is returned for the "last" row in the partition.

If you want to do this without window functions, I recomment a lateral join or a subquery:

```
select t.*, x.last_day
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select dateadd(
        day, 
        -1, 
        coalesce(min(t1.hiredate), 2100-01-01')
    ) last_day
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id = t.id and t1.hiredate > t.hiredate
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want to do this using Self Join.

Comment: @karandang: why? Window functions are the most efficient (and simple) way to do what you want.

Comment: I know but i want to understand how this can be done using Self Join. I was asked this in an interview so wanted to understand that.

Comment: @karandang: ok. I provided a solution with a lateral join.

Answer (score 0):

I think normally I'd go for a window function, but if that's off the table and your data doesn't have too many columns, then a self-join combined with grouping can look pretty clean:

```
select      a.id, a.Dept_name, a.Hiredate, 
            last_day = dateadd(day, -1, min(b.Hiredate))
from        @hireData a
left join   @hireData b on a.Id = b.Id and b.Hiredate > a.Hiredate
group by    a.id, a.Dept_name, a.Hiredate
```